# My Canadian visa is only valid for two months even though my passport is valid until 2029

Tags: visas, canada, multiple-entry

I got my passport renewed before I applied for a Canadian visitor visa and I was made aware that a multiple entry visitor visa is valid through the validity of the passport. I just received my visa and it is issued only for 2 months. I am quite angry since I paid all those fees with the hope that I would not have to do it again. Who do I get in touch with to know more about this? Why did IRCC only issue the visa for 2 months?

Comment: Have you had a visitor visa for Canada before? What was the planned purpose and timescale of your visit? 
In some cases, visitor visas normally granted for up to 6 months can be limited to a shorter period in line with the applicant’s stated plans.

Comment: A visitor visa will **not be valid for longer** than the validity of the passport. That doesn't mean it will always be valid for that long.

Comment: Unfortunately the problem you have is with the understanding of the Language, not the IRCC

Comment: Did you apply for the visa with your new passport? What is the expiration date of the visa, and of the passport?

Comment: If don’t know where you got the idea that a visa is issued for the full remaining validity of a passport, but that is definitely not the case. As @DJClayworth says, it’s a maximum, but most definitely not the norm. In many cases, you will be granted short visas initially, and as you gain trust, you may get longer and longer visas.

Comment: @jcaron The Canadian Visa Help Centre http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=417&top=16 states that a multiple entry visa “will be valid for up to 10 years or one month before your passport expires, whichever is the shorter”. I can see how the belief may have arisen if the OP didn’t read/understand all of the various sections of information about visitor visas. It sounds like the OP didn’t qualify for a multiple entry visa and has been given a single entry visa which they must use to seek admission into Canada on or before the two month expiry date?

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately for you visiting foriegn countries is considered a privilage not a right and also unfortunately for you it is a privilage that people from poorer countries often abuse. That is the main reason western countries require people to get visitor Visas in the first place.

When a visa officer looks at your application they have to make a judgement over whether they can trust you to behave yourself and return home, both now and in the future. Depending on the results of that judgement call they may refuse you a visa, they may grant you a visa but only for a short period and/or a single entry, or they may grant you a longer term visa.

The Canadian government specifies the maximum they will issue a visitor visa for, they do not specify a minimum. Don't think this is an accident.